# Css styles and images don't apply to pdf generating by Flying Saucer

Tags: java, html, css, pdf

I need to convert some html pages into pdf. After some googling i decide to use Flying Saurcer to perform it. I use this code to do so:

```
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/Developer/test.pdf"));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.getSharedContext().setNamespaceHandler(new XhtmlNamespaceHandler());
        renderer.getSharedContext().setUserAgentCallback(new CustomUserAgentCallback(renderer.getOutputDevice()));
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(out);
```

Where CustomUserAgentCallback is:

```
public class CustomUserAgentCallback extends ITextUserAgent {

    public CustomUserAgentCallback(ITextOutputDevice device) {
        super(device);
    }
/**
 *  {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
protected InputStream resolveAndOpenStream(String uri) {
    try {
        return new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(resolveURI(uri)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        XRLog.exception(String.format("Cannot resolve file with uri %s", uri));
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public String resolveURI(String uri) {
    return HttpUtils.getServletAttributes().getRequest().getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + uri;
}
}
```

So, resolveURI method forms a valid path to resources (css, images) on server.

But pdf creates without formatting, so styles are ignored as well as img.
Thanks for attention (and sorry for my English)

Comment: where is your `HTML` structure ?
one more thing PDF only supports inline `CSS` so make sure you're using it only!

Comment: ***@OP***: Make sure that the `css` paths mentioned in the html *sourceFile* have absolute path. Or at-least have the same relative path as that of your *JVM*